# Number of moves needed to turn a $2n\times2n$ chessboard monochromatic by subrectangle inversion

Tags: combinatorics

> What is the minimum number of moves needed to turn a $2n\times2n$ chessboard monochromatic by inverting subrectangles?

I believe that the solution is $2n$ – we can invert the colours of odd rows, then even columns. We try to prove this by induction. The case when $n=1$ is trivial and we observe that this works by just arranging the like colors and then inverting them ($2\cdot1=2$ moves). The general case is the same as the first part of this answer. This concludes our proof. I feel like this induction proof doesn't seem sound and also I don't know how to prove that it is the minimum. I think I can show this by somehow considering $n=1$'s case but please help.

Comment: You've given a working strategy but haven't made an argument that it's optimal. For a lower bound on the number of moves required, consider the borders between the squares on the outside edge of the board. Each of these borders needs to be "touched" at least once.